# IE8 GWT radio button not displayed

Tags: java, gwt, internet-explorer-8, radio-button

I'm getting crazy with "my friend" IE8 and GWT . I have looked for solutions in the forum, but I haven't found exactly what I was looking for . The thing is that I have declared a radioPanel for two radioButtons (radioPannel , radioRattachement) :

```
    // Ajout des listeners et des styles sur les boutons
    radioRole.setStyleName(Constants.RADIO_LISTE_PROJET);
    // radioRole.setst
    radioRole.addListener(Events.OnClick, new ClickFiltreListener(this));
    radioRole.setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
    radioRole.setHideMode(HideMode.VISIBILITY);

    radioRattachement.setStyleName(Constants.RADIO_LISTE_PROJET);
    radioRattachement.addListener(Events.OnClick, new ClickFiltreListener(
            this));
    radioRattachement.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    radioRattachement.setHideMode(HideMode.VISIBILITY);

    // Creation du groupe de radio et ajout des 2 boutons dans ce groupe
    radioGroup.add(radioRattachement);
    radioGroup.add(radioRole);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    radioGroup.setWidth(80);
    radioGroup.setHeight(80);
    radioGroup.setHideLabel(Boolean.TRUE);

    // Panel contenat le groupe de radio
    final ContentPanel radioGroupPanel = new ContentPanel();
    final FormLayout boutonPosteLayout = new FormLayout();
    // boutonPosteLayout.setPadding(Constants.INT_PADDING_0);
    // boutonPosteLayout.setLabelWidth(Constants.INT_PIXELS_40);
    radioGroupPanel.setLayout(boutonPosteLayout);
    radioGroupPanel.add(radioGroup);
```

And it works as a charm in firefox, but in Internet Explorer, the radioButtons are not displayed . Is there any issue to know ? . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you tried multiple versions of IE ? Multiple versions of SmartGWT ? This looks more like a bug

Comment: Is your doctype ok ? You need to enable the 'strict' mode for IE (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">)

Comment: Where are those `setHideMode` and `setOrientation` coming from? Which widget library are you using?

Comment: @Yanflea: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is enough. GWT doesn't work with XHTML (served as XHTML), and [trying to do XHTML while actually doing HTML will cause you more problems than it'll solve](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml)

Comment: @Thomas. Well, in my gwt/gxt app, the display is a mess in IE8 with only `<!DOCTYPE html>` (while it still works great in FF...)

Comment: The problem I have is that the radioButtons are not displayed . I thought it has to be with hiding information ( so I add setHideMode ) . The orientation is the vertical orientation I need .

Comment: @user1659746: that doesn't answer the question: you're not using vanilla GWT. Those widgets come from SmartGWT or some other widget library. You should add that library as a tag to the question (and remove the `java` tag as you're at it)

Comment: Finally I solved . It was I bit stupid . Css and position Issue . I change the width, the possition, and the radio appears . Really sorry, and thanks .